# ServiceStack OAuth Redirect URL

Tags: authentication, oauth, redirect, servicestack

The ServiceStack `AuthService` enters an infinite loop after authenticating with an OAuth provider because of this line in `OAuthProvider.cs`:

```
return authService.Redirect(session.ReferrerUrl.AddHashParam("s", "1"));
```

I can override the `ReferrerUrl` with a custom `AuthUserSession` when configuring ServiceStack authentication, but it feels kind of dirty.

Is there a cleaner way to redirect successful authentications, based on the authentication provider?

Comment: How are you originally calling it? going straight to /auth/provider? or do get redirected there?

Comment: I'm just linking to `/api/auth/twitter`. I guess I could redirect there, but it seems like an unnecessary round-trip :\.

Answer (score 2):

Now in v3.40 (on [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack) / [GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/downloads)) it will detect if there was no Referrer or if it was itself (i.e. from /auth) and if so, will either Redirect to:

Any [RedirectUrl](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AuthProvider.cs#L32) you have defined on the AuthProvider, e.g. for TwitterAuthProvider you can can add this to your Web.Config:

```
<add key="oauth.twitter.RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:1337/redirectafterauth" />
```

Otherwise it will try redirect to your home page if it's set in **EndpointHostConfig.WebHostUrl** or will try work it out via the RequestUri.